# Jquery Make Notification Like Net Send

Tags: jquery

How to make notification like net send in windows :

I have home.php, any user can access. Sometimes I need maintenance that page, so I dont need to call them. I just give notification using jquery. So when they open home.php, jquery notification will show that we will maintenance.

I have searched in google, but I think dont know whats the point key. Anyone have suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question, but here is my shot.

Just replace your main div for your default message.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').html('THIS PAGE IS UNDER MAINTENANCE, PLEASE COME BACK SOON');
});
```

OR the content can be a HTML page with a nice style.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#content").load("maintenance_page.html");
});
```